# How can I get the value of JavaFX DatePicker?

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I am trying to get the value from the DatePicker of JavaFX.

```
@FXML
DatePicker datesTimes;
```

I have tried simply getting the value

```
System.out.println(datesTimes.getValue());
```

but I get an error and I cannot import it either.

> java: cannot access java.time.LocalDate --
> class file for java.time.LocalDate not found

I tried copying some of the answers on here, however, they all seem outdated.

```
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(datesTimes.getValue());

    datesTimes.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>() {
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);

        {
            datesTimes.setPromptText(pattern.toLowerCase());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(LocalDate date) {
            if (date != null) {
                return dateFormatter.format(date);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate fromString(String string) {
            if (string != null && !string.isEmpty()) {
                return LocalDate.parse(string, dateFormatter);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
```

I get the error:

> Usage of API documented as @since 1.8+

Please help me I have tried very hard but I cannot fix this problem

**EDIT - Minimal, Reproducible Example**

I'm using java 16 with Intellij.

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <DatePicker fx:id="datesTimes" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="79.0" />
            <Button layoutX="64.0" layoutY="133.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getBtnDate" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    DatePicker datesTimes;

    public void getBtnDate(){
        //output date picker value
        //datesTimes.getValue();
    }

}
```

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What build tool are you using, if any? In other words, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Slaw Hello and thanks for the response. I created the minimal example, please tell me how to fix it if you can.

Comment: don't see you using the converter anywhere in the example..

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for the response. Yeah it goes in the getBtnDate(), I didn't want to show duplicate info

Answer (score 1):

If you enter a date in the picker via any method other than selecting it from the calendar, `getValue()` will return null. Instead you need to use the converter on the text of its editor.

Here is what I use:

```
public static LocalDate safeGetDateFromDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker) {
    return datePicker.getConverter().fromString(datePicker.getEditor().getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error when I try this: usage of API documented as @since 1.8+

Comment: I have no idea on that one. A quick search looks like it may be a configuration problem of your IDE.

Comment: @cazhiumakanam Check you [project configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html). Are you positively using Java 16? Is your language level set to 16?

Comment: As an FYI, the project that my snippet came from is Java 11.

Comment: Solved, thank you all! turns out I was in fact using Java 16, however, the language level was set to default. I changed it to 13 (because it was the highest option available). Now simply `datePicker.getValue()` returns the user-chosen date.